# Use the same color for two materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

In my current project, made in Cycles, I would like to be able to use the same color for two completely different materials. That way, I can tweak the color easily and everything will still look fine. Is there any way to do this?

They are emissive materials.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to create an RGB node and then make a group out of it. Then add that group to the other materials. When you change the color in the grouped RGB node, it will change in all materials.